# Bash cgi script sending email as apache@ user and ignoring mail command parameters

Tags: bash, apache, centos, cgi

I am using Centos 7, Apache 2.4.6, Postfix 2.10.1

I have a bash script in cgi-bin that sends an email, using the following syntax:

echo -e "Body" | mail -s "subject" "myemailaddress@hotmail.com"

If I execute this on the command line then it works as expected and the email is sent.

However if I initiate the same script line from a webpage through the cgi-bin directory then the cgi script doesn't throw an error, but I receive an email from apache@mydomain.com with an empty subject and body.

I have set execute permissions on the script.
I have amended the selinux setting httpd_can_sendmail.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Try to run the script as the same user as your web server (probably the Apache user). See if you get more error messages. Also, try redirecting standard err to standard out and see if that gives you more info (put 2>&1 at the end).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Nicholas. I tried the command sudo -u apache echo -e "Body" | mail -s "subject" "myemailaddress@hotmail.com" and it worked fine. Although I do believe that it is running the command as the apache user as I'm using a text file for debugging and that file is owned by apache. I tried redirecting standard err to stdout and no additional error messages showed up.

Comment: if it worked via sudo - u, then I suspect the issue is something in your environment as yourself that is being carried over. If you do su - apache and try it (the su - meaning, load up apache's environment and not your own), does that break it?  Other things I would reach for if it were my machine/script: try a different mail program (e.g. mailx or nail), set a return address (-r), try running it as a different user. Also, just FYI, you probably have a security vuln.   It's a variation on SQL injection. Think what happens if body is set with a double quote inside it: test";cat /etc/passwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to satisfy my requirement, however in the end I had to abandon bash and use perl instead.  That is frustrating, as the only thing that the bash script wouldn't do was to send the email.
All the same user permissions with the perl script and it works.
Thanks to Nicholas for his suggestions.